# Testing Angular and Chart JS

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, chart.js

Currently I am receiving the following error in my jest unit test in an Angular application that is testing a component that uses ChartJS.

`TypeError: auto_1.default is not a constructor`

The chart/graph displays fine and I am able to switch between different datasets that feed into this presentation component from an external data source.

I have tried importing the  `Chart from 'chart.js/auto';` into the test, mocking various functions that create the chart and to no success. Importing ChartJS into a test file, or creating a new chart to test in the test does nothing and I still receive the same error.

The .spec file:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing'
import { GraphDisplayComponent } from './graph-display.component';


describe('GraphDisplayComponent', () => {
  let component: GraphDisplayComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<GraphDisplayComponent>;


  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [GraphDisplayComponent],
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(GraphDisplayComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

The .ts of the component

```
import {
  Component,
  ElementRef,
  Input,
  OnInit,
  ViewChild,
} from '@angular/core';
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-graph-display',
  templateUrl: './graph-display.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./graph-display.component.scss'],
})
export class GraphDisplayComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() chartData: any;
  @ViewChild('canvas', { static: true }) canvas!: ElementRef;
  chart!: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.chart = new Chart(this.canvas.nativeElement, this.chartData);
  }

}
```